# the problems with read Doc or Docx file in java

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, hwpf

I am having this problem with reading a `.doc` or `.docx` file in Java:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument`

I don't understand why this is happening and would appreciate any help getting rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that sounds like you haven't put the relevant Apache POI jar file(s) into the classpath you're using at execution time. Without more information, that's about all we can say.

- Find out which jar files are required
- Find out what's controlling your classpath (which will depend on what kind of app you're running)
- Make sure all the jar files *are* in place
- Rerun
- Profit :)

For example, from the command line, on Windows, you might want to run:

```
java -cp .;poi-whatever.jar foo.bar.Test
```

(Replace the jar file name and your entry point name appropriately.)

Comment: I'm run demo the programs read file .doc and .docx
how to set classpath???

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:484)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument`

Comment: You haven't told us anything about how you're trying to run the code.

Comment: I added the library of Apache POI 3.8 in the project.now,what must I do next?

Comment: :that [link](http://nq8.upanh.com/b1.s30.d1/0bba3001d6a1504cfae22ad4a7c89c28_49271818.help2.png)

Comment: that class isn't available on my system.what must I do???