# the problems with read Doc or Docx file in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, hwpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the problems with read Doc or Docx file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499372/the-problems-with-read-doc-or-docx-file-in-java)

I'm have a problems with programs read file word in java.Then I run programs,it's report error as follows:`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)....`

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument

This is telling you that somewhere in your code, you need `org.apache.poit.hwpf.HWPFDocument`, and that class isn't available on your system. It appears to be part of [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) which you can [download here](https://poi.apache.org/download.html).

Comment: I added the library of Apache POI 3.8 in the project.now,what must I do next?

Comment: @user1683695 Follow Jon Skeet's instructions on your other question.